# Can tensorflow scan and only keep the final result?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code calculates the sum of an array with `tf.scan`.
Would tensorflow allocate a 6 element array to hold the six partial sums?
Or, tensorflow is smart enough only allocate a 1 element array to hold the partial sums?

How to know for sure?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
s = tf.scan(lambda a, x: a + x, elems)
# s == [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
final_s = s[-1]  # final_s == 21
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(final_s))
```

---

The following code leads to out of memory on a machine with 16 GB.

I guess tensorflow never tries to optimize scan.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = tf.ones(int(1e9), dtype=np.float32)  # 4GB
s = tf.scan(lambda a, x: a + x, elems)
final_s = s[-1]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(final_s))
```

Comment: theano is smart enough to optimize the scan: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html

Comment: even with `back_prop=False`, it still gives out of memory.

Comment: tf.scan is so disappointing.

Comment: If you only want the final result, you should use `tf.foldl`. Maybe that one is more efficient in this case.

Comment: @xdurch0 `tf.foldl` and `back_prop=False` still lead to out of memory for my 2nd example.