# Make `while_loop` run faster

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

Since `tf.scan` gives me [oom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534114/can-tensorflow-scan-and-only-keep-the-final-result) even with `back_prop=False`, I try `while_loop` and do the awfully long derivative by hand.

But my `while_loop` is slow.
Is it possible to speed up the `while_loop`?

Result:

```
result: 1000000
second per iteration 5.064262390136719e-06
```

Test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time


def make_while_loop(counts, dtype=np.int32):
    i = tf.get_variable('i', dtype=np.int32, initializer=dtype(0))
    one = tf.constant(1, dtype=dtype)
    loop_ends = tf.constant(counts, dtype=dtype)
    condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, loop_ends)
    increment = lambda i: tf.add(i, one)
    return tf.while_loop(condition, increment, [i], back_prop=False)


def main():
    count = int(1e6)
    i = make_while_loop(count)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.graph.finalize()
        sess.run(init)
        st = time.time()
        print("result:", sess.run(i)[1])
        en = time.time()
        print("second per iteration", (en - st) / count)


main()
```

Comment: The loop methods like `tf.while_loop` and `tf.map_fn` are slower than vectorization method in tensorflow. The more loop you have, the more obvious the problem is. You should use vectorization as much as possible according to your needs.

Comment: I have approximated the answer by batching and partially vectorizing the loop. I can't completely avoid using a loop.

Comment: Personal suggestions: Maybe you should elaborate on your complete question. What do you want to do, what parts have you simplified, and what parts can't avoid loops?. If you only want the final result, you can use `tf.reduce_sum` directly and so on. So if it's a simple count like the one in the question, I don't think anyone can give you any advice that will solve your real question.