# TensorFlow while_loop eats all the memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, optimization, while-loop

I want to make a while loop. No, I mean I *need* a while loop.

1. The loop updates data in-place according to a gradient
2. Each update also depends on the previous update.

I have tried my best to partially vectorize the loop by approximation and batching. I can't avoid using a loop.

The bad thing is that my `while_loop` is eating all the GPU memory.

I have tried to move the definition of the assignment op out of the memory... But that leads to just one assignment before the loop starts. I want to have one assignment in each iteration of the loop.

How to fix the crazy memory consumption?

Many thanks.

Test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
from functools import partial


def precursor_condition(end_index, loop_index):
    return tf.less(loop_index, end_index)


def make_condition(end_index):
    return partial(precursor_condition, end_index)


def get_gradient(x):
    y = x * x
    return tf.gradients(y, x, stop_gradients=x)[0]


def precursor_loop_body(data, one, loop_index):
    data_prev = data[loop_index - 1]
    data_now = data[loop_index]
    assignment = tf.assign(data_now, get_gradient(data_now) + data_prev)
    with tf.control_dependencies([assignment]):
        return tf.add(loop_index, one)


def make_loop_body(data, one):
    return partial(precursor_loop_body, data, one)


def make_while_loop(data, dtype=np.int32):
    i = tf.get_variable('i', dtype=np.int32, initializer=1)
    one = tf.constant(1, dtype=dtype)
    end_ix = tf.constant(data.get_shape()[0], dtype=dtype)
    condition = make_condition(end_ix)
    body = make_loop_body(data, one)
    loop_vars = [i]
    return tf.while_loop(condition, body, loop_vars,
                         back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=1)


def main():
    print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
    count = int(1e9)
    initializer = tf.range(count, dtype=np.float32)
    data = tf.get_variable('data', dtype=np.float32,
                           trainable=False, initializer=initializer)

    print("initial data type", type(data))

    while_loop = make_while_loop(data)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.graph.finalize()
        sess.run(init)
        st = time.time()
        print("result:", sess.run([while_loop, data]))
        en = time.time()
        print("second per iteration", (en - st) / count)


main()
```

By the way, `tf.scan` is even more horrible in terms of the memory consumption ([I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534114/can-tensorflow-scan-and-only-keep-the-final-result?noredirect=1#comment99660163_56534114).)

Comment: Have you considered that the reason for it going slow might not be because you're using a `while_loop`, but because you're doing machine learning and *in general* machine learning eats up GPU memory?

Comment: It is not even a neural net. I think the test code is simple. But tensorflow still gives out of memory error for this simple example.